# i want to add safari to my imac dock?

Tags: safari, dock

I have tried right clicking, doesn't work. I have tried to drag icon once up on my dock to applications or desktop, doesn't work. basically i have to seek safari constantly open in order to easily access it, this seems ridiculous. i usually can figure these things out, but not with my new imac.

please someone, step-by-step answer that works please!!

thanks,
oona

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder to your desktop, then drag the Safari icon in the Finder window to your dock.

Answer (score 1):

When Safari is running, right click the icon in the dock, choose Options -> Keep in Dock.